Cloning windows to another partition in a different ssd drive
My windows 10 is installed on "Samsung SSD 750 EVO 120GB" and after checking crystaldiskinfo, it's health is at 1% with 38 tb written. since it's on such a low health I'm planning to clone my windows to my NVME ssd, but it's a single 1 tb partition which contains personal files on it.
I was wondering if I can allocate 150 GB on a separate partition on my NVME and clone my windows to it.
i'm planning to use AOMEI Partition Assistant . Will this process face any issues?
is using the windows cloning option in"AOMEI Partition Assistant" enough> or do I need to clone additional system partitions?

A 750 EVO @ 1% health with only 38TB written? What does Samsung Magician say? It's recommended to always store user data on a partition other than C: by right-clicking on each user data folder [Documents, Downloads, etc] and opening the folder properties, going to the Location tab, and changing it to a different partition. This also makes imaging Windows far easier and convenient, separating the OS and user data

Samsung magician shows health as "good" but crystaldiskinfo shows 1% . i googled  and looks like the TBW for this model is only 35 ! so i got the impression that the drive might be dying
